# How does one import an old Exchange email archive into Apple Mail?

Tags: email, gmail, import

I have an archive of old emails from a former project that I worked on. On that project, I was given my own Exchange email address and subsequently have a ton of emails for which I created an archive. That old Exchange address and account are closed. How can I import all the emails into Apple Mail or Gmail?

Comment: Do you mean you have an `.ost` file? If not, what kind of "archive" format is it? Was the archive created with Microsoft Outlook or with another mail client?

Comment: Thx for responding. Yes, I have a .ost file that was created from Outlook. I also have all the emails still sitting in my Apple Mail since the account was linked. I could export them from Apple Mail. I just want to delete the old Outlook account when I am done.

Comment: Can I just move all of the emails from one mailbox to another? Then delete the account?

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://www.macworld.com/article/2151263/importing-windows-outlook-messages-into-apples-mail.html) - hope it helps.

Comment: Thx. It does help! It is in progress so hopefully, it will work out for me. I was able to make an mbox archive of the Exchange mailbox, then import it to back to my mailbox and finally move the emails to the mailbox where I wanted them.  Looks like the biggest drawback is they are moving from the Import verrrrryyy slowly. It is 13K+ emails and the move is crawling along...but it seems to be working. thanks for the article!